# How to create a nix project with the python package streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit, nix, nix-flake

```
{
  description = "virtual environment with python and streamlit";
  inputs.nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
  inputs.flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let
        pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
        python=pkgs.python311;
        python_packages= python.withPackages(ps: with ps;[
          ipython
          matplotlib
          pandas
          streamlit
        ]);


        myDevTools = [
          python_packages
        ];
      in {
        devShells.default = pkgs.mkShell {
          buildInputs = myDevTools;
        };
      });
}
```

the command nix develop works fine until I add the package streamlit

> error:
> … while calling the 'derivationStrict' builtin
>
> ```
>      at /builtin/derivation.nix:9:12: (source not available)
>
>    … while evaluating derivation 'nix-shell'
>      whose name attribute is located at /nix/store/s1z7nb9n6r5n0r34fabp6yybwkbr8mjk-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:303:7
>
>    … while evaluating attribute 'buildInputs' of derivation 'nix-shell'
>
>      at /nix/store/s1z7nb9n6r5n0r34fabp6yybwkbr8mjk-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:350:7:
>
>       349|       depsHostHost                = lib.elemAt (lib.elemAt dependencies 1) 0;
>       350|       buildInputs                 = lib.elemAt (lib.elemAt dependencies 1) 1;
>          |       ^
>       351|       depsTargetTarget            = lib.elemAt (lib.elemAt dependencies 2) 0;
>
>    (stack trace truncated; use '--show-trace' to show the full trace)
>
>    error: undefined variable 'streamlit'
>
>    at /nix/store/zxv0741pn2r7h0vk1f1i9knvybfh3yff-source/flake.nix:15:11:
>
>        14|           pandas
>        15|           streamlit
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streamlit isn't a python package if you search through Nix packages: https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=23.05&show=streamlit&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=streamlit

So you have to add it here:

```hs
myDevTools = [
    python_packages pkgs.streamlit
];
```

The streamlit pip packages don't seem to be in Nix, but [this page](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Python) tells you how to add anything from the cheeseshop.

```hs
my-python-packages = ps: with ps; [
  # ...
  (
    buildPythonPackage rec {
      pname = "deserialize";
      version = "1.8.3";
      src = fetchPypi {
        inherit pname version;
        sha256 = "sha256-0aozmQ4Eb5zL4rtNHSFjEynfObUkYlid1PgMDVmRkwY=";
      };
      doCheck = false;
      propagatedBuildInputs = [
        # Specify dependencies
        pkgs.python3Packages.numpy
      ];
    }
  )
];
```